# JavaScript array reduction

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function init(){
var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
var i;

var week = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"];
var weekend = ["saturday","sunday"];

panel.innerHTML+="weekdays: "+ week;
panel.innerHTML+="<hr>weekend days: "+ weekend;

for(i=0; i<weekend.length; i++)
{
    week[week.length]=weekend[i];
}

panel.innerHTML+="<hr>increased with weekend days: "+week;

week-=2;

panel.innerHTML+="<hr>reduced back to weekdays: "+week;
}
window.onload=init;
```

this is the main js code it is loaded from another html file. everything is working fine until the end. the last output should be "reduced back to weekdays: monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday" but what im getting is this "reduced back to weekdays: NaN", what does this error mean and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 11):

You should reduce the array length by 2, not the array itself:

`week.length -= 2;`

Example:

```
var week = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
week.length -= 2;

console.log(week);
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I feel like it's better practice to use the well-defined array methods rather than messing directly with its length, but maybe you can explain if I'm wrong?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure reducing length is well defined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: Too used to data hiding, I guess. Link to the ECMAScript standard documenting this and I'll +1 you.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.1 `While newLen < oldLen repeat,` part

Comment: 15.4 array objects : whenever the length property is changed, every property whose name is an array index whose value is not smaller than the new length is automatically deleted. http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4 - But I prefer to use functions to change things like this.

Comment: Basically modifying `.length` or a numeric (Not all numeric but Uint32, other numbers will just be normal object properties) property of an array always invokes a setter function

Comment: Ha ha, yes, I'm talking about _programming_ not the internals of a language specification.  I don't mind using `=` to assign values to an object (instead of `setAttribute()`), but when it does something like delete items, or reload documents (`location.href=` vs `location.assign`) I think the functions are more readable.

Answer (score 5):

maybe you have to change:

```
week-=2;
```

to:

```
week.splice(-2);
```

Edit (thanks @Esailija):

splice return the removed elements, so you have just to call the splice method, without assign the result back to the array:

```
week.splice(-2);
```

Comment: `.splice` returns an array of the removed elements, he wants it to have weekdays again not the weekend days

Comment: This answer is the most appropriate for the desired behaviour.  Assigning a value to length feels dirty (the length of other types is read-only), and `pop()` is not scalable (if you wanted to discard a lot of items from the end of an array) because it's a stack metaphor .

Answer (score 2):

You can't subtract a number from an array and expect meaningful results. That is mixing types and of course the behavior will be weird.

To get the weekend days out, use the `pop()` method of the array object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function init(){
var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
var i;

var week = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"];
var weekend = ["saturday","sunday"];

panel.innerHTML+="weekdays: "+ week;
panel.innerHTML+="<hr>weekend days: "+ weekend;

for(i=0; i<weekend.length; i++)
{
    week[week.length]=weekend[i];
}

panel.innerHTML+="<hr>increased with weekend days: "+week;

week.length -= 2;

panel.innerHTML+="<hr>reduced back to weekdays: "+week;
}
window.onload=init;
```

but it's not a good way to use `.length` for setter!